# newton method divergence using syms / subs

Tags: optimization

I am programming newtons method, the following code snippet shows what I have done to the main function.  I have a data structure with just the function, which is x^2+y^2 for now.  the value for data.x0 is [1;1] (close to the solution) and the value for data.e is 0.01

The update xk is running away from the origin instead of towards it.  In fact, I can get this code to work for a few problems when I specify data.x0 very close to a local minimum or inside a deep pit on the function.  otherwise it diverges even for very simple functions.

My intuition tells me it is a result of using the hessian and gradient functions from the symbolic toolbox instead of analytic methods as I had been warned of.   Any thoughts?

```
    xk=data.x0
    grad=gradient(data.f)
    grad_xk=double(subs(grad,[x;y],xk))
    hess=hessian(data.f)
    norm_grad_xk=0;                                       
  for i=1:length(grad_xk)                               
      norm_grad_xk=norm_grad_xk+grad_xk(i)^2;          
  end
    norm_grad_xk=sqrt(norm_grad_xk)                    
    mag_fun_xk=double(subs(data.f,[x;y],xk))                     
        while (norm_grad_xk)>data.e*(1+abs(mag_fun_xk))
    hess_xk=double(subs(hess,[x;y],xk))
    invhess_xk=inv(hess_xk)
    xk=xk-invhess_xk*grad_xk
    % ll=horzcat(ll,xk)
    norm_grad_xk=0;                                       
  for i=1:length(grad_xk)                               
      norm_grad_xk=norm_grad_xk+grad_xk(i)^2          
  end
    norm_grad_xk=sqrt(norm_grad_xk)                    
    mag_fun_xk=double(subs(data.f,[x;y],xk))
        end
```